# Links not working for multiple website under having multiple stores

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

[image]For last 2 days i am trying to make two website with different multistore, all the method i follow is correct and i got multiwebsite with multi stores but problem is that only home page is running fine, inner pages like category and product listing pages not working properly .
And i can not add different price for different view stores .
please help me: thanks in advance

in second screen shot i create a store view.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your website and give URL must equal 
means index.php  Mage::run('**websitecode**', 'website');
and given website name in admin manage->store.
website code '**websitecode**' must same website name give any ..
and one more thing 
add new website URL in **system->configuration->general(tab)->web** :(select your store)
unsecure
Base Link URL =  **{{unsecure_base_url}}websitecode/**

secure
Base Link URL =  **{{secure_base_url}}websitecode/**

and set home page in default page:
CMS Home Page = "your cms home page"

here all **websitecode** is same

Comment: Thanks for answer but i already did the same, i have no issue with homepage but the main issue with the inner pages not working with second website having different multistores. every time it redirect to default store.

Comment: please check when your are redirect to home page at that time your URL content your websidecode?? like http://localhost/multisotore/websitecode/index.php
http://localhost/multistore/websitecode/contacts/   for contact us page

Comment: my website not redirect to homepage it goes to same page which one i clicked but default website and store.